# Como diminuir o tempo de resposta de uma conexão malsucedida ao usar Ksoap2?

Tags: java, android, web-service

Quando o servidor ou serviço (IIS) esta *off*, o tempo de reposta do web-service de que há alguma falha de conexão é muito longa. Nesse tempo o aplicativo (Android) solicita o fechamento devido a inatividade.
Têm como diminuir esse tempo ou tratar de outra forma uma possível exceção?

```
public String getTesteConexao(){
    String returns = "";
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_GET_TESTE_CONEXAO);
        request.addProperty("senha", TAG_CHAVE);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(urlFinal);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        returns = (String) envelope.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Exception: " + e.getMessage() + "\nCause: " + e.getCause();
    }
    return returns;
}
```

Comment: Já achei a solução, que por sinal é bem simples. Foi falta de procurar um pouco mais ou usar as termos certos. É só passar como argumento um valor em milissegundos na linha `HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(urlFinal, 5000)`;

Comment: Para que a pergunta fique nos padrões aceitos dentro do SOpt, por favor, siga os passos: retire a parte "RESOLVIDO" do título, coloque o seu comentário como resposta e marque como solução a resposta que colocou.

Comment: rapha, removi o "resolvido" do título e publiquei seu comentário como resposta (em modo wiki), se quiser publicar uma resposta, me avise e deleto a que postei.

Comment: Tranquilo @brasofilo! É que não sabia no dia como proceder. Valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Achei a solução, que por sinal é bem simples. Foi falta de procurar um pouco mais ou usar as termos certos. É só passar como argumento um valor em milissegundos na linha

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(urlFinal, 5000);
```

<sub><sub>*Publicado originalmente como comentário pelo autor da pergunta.*</sub></sub>

Answer (score 0):

MSG-TIME_OUT Você coloca o tempo de resposta em milissegundos

```
    int MSG_TIMEOUT = 15000;
httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, MSG_TIMEOUT);
```